# How to cut all Lines/Characters in R after specific Characters

Tags: r, text, replace, finance, sec

I am currently taking a course that teaches textual analysis in R. As I am fairly new to R, I could not figure out yet how to cut all Lines after a specific set of characters.

**For example, I have the following given:**

```r
documentName <- "Hello my name is Johann my had is the largest to be deleted X"
```

**My desired outcome is:**

```r
documentName <- "Hello my name is Johann"
```

So far I have tried the following but it is not getting me anywhere.

```r
gsub("(\Johann).*\\","",documentName)
```

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, capturing all content appearing before `Johann`:

```
x <- "Hello my name is Johann my had is the largest to be deleted"
out <- sub("^(.*\\bJohann)\\b.*$", "\\1", x)
out

[1] "Hello my name is Johann"
```

Another approach, stripping off all content appearing after `Johann`:

```
sub("(?<=\\bJohann)\\s+.*$", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes i was looking for this regular expression but could not come up with it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_remove()` from package `dplyr`

```r
str_remove(documentName, "(?<=Johann).*")
[1] "Hello my name is Johann"
```

or adjust your `gsub()` regex to

```r
gsub("(?<=Johann).*", "", documentName, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Hello my name is Johann"
```